# Why Qt .pro files add source according to different platform doesn't work?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I want to configure a Qt.pro file for my project, I write my pro file like this:

```
unix {
SOURCES += a.cpp
}

win32 {
SOURCES += b.cpp
}
```

but a.cpp and b.cpp both included in qtcreator when I am in Windows, I look some explain is same as mine, see https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-language.html, I dont't known where is wrong? What is right to configure?  my Qt version is 5.12.0

Comment: What do you mean by "both included in qtcreator"?

Comment: When you compile your project, do you use both files?

Comment: @MrEricSir I mean when I working on windows, I want use b.cpp as source and when I working on linux use a.cpp, but now they are all added in Source No matter what system I use, this method is Provided by qmake Manual , so I don't known where is wrong?

Comment: @eyllanesc no，i want use different file in different platform as i config

Comment: Do you ask why a.cpp and b.cpp are visible to you in your IDE? I think it's sometimes useful. Suppose you decide to do refactoring, you can see implementation files on all platforms and move duplicated code to a base class.

Comment: @MherDidaryan There are too many dependencies, and I can't refactor them. I just wonder why the method qmake manual are different from the actual ones.

Comment: I'm not sure what qmake manual says, please provide some links. And I'm still not sure what do you mean by  "both included in qtcreator". If you mean why those file are visible to you(not hidden) in editor, then it's the same in other editors too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After my testing, this method is correct. Although a.cpp and b.cpp will be displayed in qtcreator at the same time, the MakeFile generated by qmake will not contain other platforms.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why your code doesn't work, but recommend you to use macroses in the same *.cpp/*.h file to check the current platform because you may have the common functionality for these platforms.

For example:

```
#ifdef Q_OS_WIN32 // or Q_OS_WIN64. the code/function for Windows
void fun() 
{
   commonFunction();
}
#endif

#ifdef Q_OS_LINUX // or Q_OS_UNIX ...
void fun()
{
   commonFunction();
}
#endif

void commonFunction()
{
    //...
}
```

or

```
void fun()
{
    #ifdef Q_OS_WIN64
       // code for windows
    #endif
    #ifdef Q_OS_LINUX
       // code for linux
    #endif
    // a common code...
}
```

Comment: I will consider use this method If Iwant to refactor the code,but now I just need a method to config the project to Qt .pro

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a bug in Qt Creator. I see the same thing where the projects tree shows source files that should have been excluded by a qmake conditional. They don't seem to compile into the project. But it makes searching for text within the project very difficult as you get a lot of false hits. And if you open one of the files QtCreator will try to compile it, which can result in errors.

If anyone knows a fx I'd be interested in learning about it.

I'm using QtCreator 4.8.2 with Qt 5.11.3